# Selecting elements within the vector inaccuracy in Swirl?

Tags: r, swirl

I made an anonymous function to select the first element of the vector 
Then to select the last element of the vector. When I selected the last element, it said Incorrect. When I selected the second element, it said correct. I am tracking R is 1 based. NOT zero based. So when I select the last element of the vector should it not be x[3]???

***The first part: My function, what I used to select the first element per the problem.***
| Try using evaluate() along with an anonymous function to return the first element of
| the vector c(8, 4, 0). Your anonymous function should only take one argument which
| should be a variable `x`.

> evaluate(function(x){x[1]}, c(8, 4, 0))
>   [1] 8

| You got it!

***The second part of the problem: Select the last element of the vector***

| Now try using evaluate() along with an anonymous function to return the last element
| of the vector c(8, 4, 0). Your anonymous function should only take one argument which
| should be a variable `x`.

> evaluate(function(x){x[3]}, c(8, 4, 0))
>   [1] 0

| That's not exactly what I'm looking for. Try again. Or, type info() for more options.

| You may need to recall how to index vector elements. Remember that your anonymous
| function should only have one argument, and that argument should be named `x`. Using
| the length() function in your anonymous function may help you.

> evaluate(function(x){x[2]}, c(8, 4, 0))
>   [1] 4

| You are really on a roll!

What the heck, I had to use x[2] in order to select the last element of the vector. Why is it not x[3]?

I am using Swirl right now in R.

Comment: Is this from a particular swirl course? Maybe the course is just wrong? Can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with the commands you ran to run this swirl lession?

Answer (score 0):

What Swirl expected was to use the `length()` argument to find the last element in the vector, as in:

```
evaluate(function(x){x[length(x)]}, c(8, 4, 0))
```

This exercise is in module 9 of the *R programming* swirl course. About 2/3 through the lesson, I replicate the correct answer.

[image]

Comment: But if it worked with `x[2]` it must not be actually looking at the code. Why would it work with `x[2]`?

Comment: @MrFlick - Without debugging this further, I can't explain the information posted in the original question. I have demonstrated, however, that my answer is correct.

Comment: OK. It's just a bad test. When checking if the answer is right, it uses a vector that has length 2: https://github.com/swirldev/swirl_courses/blob/ac5c6142b7a51698c16fe8587222284779d66122/R_Programming/Functions/customTests.R#L101 So the reason why `x[2]` works is just a bit of random luck.

Comment: Hi Len, Thanks. I am just wondering why x[2] selects the last element of the vector but x[1] selects the first element in the vector. R is a 1 based index?

do you suspect it is an error with the Swirl program?

Comment: You're welcome. Based on the comment from @MrFlick , it does appear to be an error in the Swirl program.